# gimp configure default font size in config file (gimprc)

Tags: fonts, gimp, fontconfig

Is it possible to configure the deafult font size in gimprc?

from `man gimprc`, I see:

```
(default-font "Sans")
```

Can the string "Sans" be modified to specify the font size? Where can I find a full format specification of the font parameter?

Comment: Do you want to modify the font in the UI or the font in the text tool?

Comment: the font in the text tool. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool options are kept in the... `tool-options` subdirectory of your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/). The name and format is self-explanatory, for instance, my `tool-options/gimp-text-tool` file contains:

```
# GIMP gimp-text-tool options

(palette "Basic")
(font "Gilgongo")
(font-size 60.000000)

# end of gimp-text-tool options
```

Comment: The above setting appears to not be taking effect. I've also added `(global-font yes)` but the default font size for the Text tool remains the same

Comment: Works for me. Did you did this when Gimp was running? Where is that `global-font` setting described? It is not in my `gimp-text-tool` file.

Comment: `GIMP-Warning: Error while parsing '/etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc' in line 210: unexpected number '60.000', expected string constant - fatal parse error`. I replaced it with a string, now it does not complain. But the default font size is still 18

Comment: Ah, so you are still editing `gimprc`? The right place is the `tool-options/gimp-text-tool` file, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the difference between gimprc and gimp profile. It works now

Comment: you might be able to answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1213798/specify-lower-left-corner-of-text-box